# "cannot import name 'geometry' from 'tkinter'"

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying a "Hello World" test on a GUI window, imported from tkinter. The problem starts when I try to run it and an error pops up in the terminal of VScode:
`cannot import name 'geometry' from 'tkinter'`.

```
import csv
from fileinput import filename
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Frame, Entry, END
from tkinter import geometry

class attendance_tester(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()   
root = Tk()     
root.geometry("800x800")
frm = ttk.Frame(root, padding=10)
frm.grid()
ttk.Label(frm, text="Hello World!").grid(column=0, row=0)
ttk.Button(frm, text="Quit", command=root.destroy).grid(column=1, row=0)
app = attendance_tester(master=root)
app.master.title("Student Attendance Program")
app.mainloop()
root.destroy()


from attendance_create import (func_create, func_edit_add,
                               func_ask_edit, func_edit_change, func_edit_sub,
                               func_edit_view, func_open, func_first_change)

with open(r"C:\\Users\\user_name\\Desktop\\attendance_sheet.csv") as file:
    csv_file_read = csv.reader(file)
    for row in csv_file_read:
        print(row)
func_open()
attend_test = attendance_tester(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I have tried seemingly every solution I could find on the internet. I really need some help.

Comment: Why are you trying to import `geometry` in the first place?  This code does not use it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to import geometry to use it. Just remove the import line and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldnt import it from the first place you just need to import the tkinter itself just remove that line and it should be just fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to import geometry, it works without that import line.

Also, you have a few duplicate imports which may become confusing. It's better to stick to fewer imports:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Frame, Entry, END
```